# Other sys admin hangouts

Tags: untagged

ServerFault is a great resource!  Glad to have found it.  What other online resources / forums / newsgroups do you frequent that are similar to serverfault?

I'm looking for high-traffic sites, the ones you can go to when you have a very specific question and have at least a little better chance that someone has "been there done that" with your needle-in-the-haystack questions ;-)

Answer (score 7):

`alt.sysadmin.recovery`

Answer (score 5):

why no one mentioned IRC? Freenode is a wonderful place to hang out, and there are several rooms (#lopsa, #debian, #unix, #bash) that tend to be full of sysadmins

Comment: This is true. I hang out on #LOPSA, and sometimes #AMANDA. #puppet is great, too.

Comment: #bash on freenode is a place that's easy to learn incredible amounts in.

Comment: true. I'm usually on #rhel and #rhev myself

Answer (score 4):

SAGE's [sage-members](http://www.sage.org/lists/) list.

Comment: Or the local equivalent.

Comment: Also the Also the LOPSA mailing lists. (discuss and tech in particular) http://lopsa.org/mailman/listinfo

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of forums online that you can look into. the ServerFault family being some of them, but you already know about those. =)

- For Microsoft based help, try Petri.co.il's forums. There is a gaggle of Microsoft MVPs that hang out there, including Mr. Petri himself.
- TechGenix has a number of sites under its umbrella such as [isaserver.org](http://forums.isaserver.org/), [msexchange.org](http://forums.msexchange.org/), [windowssecurity.com](http://www.security-forums.com/) (message boards forward to security-forums.com), windowsnetworking.com (message boards also forward to security-forums.com) and [virtualizationadmin.com](http://forums.virtualizationadmin.com/). Each has forums with varying levels of activity. Windowssecurity.com's forums are the former Security-Forums.com and as such tends to move well beyond Windows security in spite of the name of the domain. Indicentally, Security-Forums.com will forward you to the WindowsSecurity.com forums.
- Some might cringe at what I'm about to suggest, but I think it should be mentioned: Experts-Exchange.com. And yes, [you can really get a free account](http://thenonapeptide.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-get-free-experts-exchange.html) in spite of their filthy lies to the contrary.
- The new [Sysadmin-Network.com](http://www.sysadmin-network.com/) is budding (Thanks to Matt Simmons for giving me the tip!) and has the potential to be a lot bigger than what it currently is. Why don't you join and help us grow it?
- I've heard some halfway decent reviews of Daniweb.com's community but have never joined it myself.
- Google has come back with some interesting results that I've never heard of before such as SysAdmin TALK Forums and sysadminforum.com. I can't pledge for their usefulness though and so won't provide a link to them.
- Each individual systems vendor will oftentimes have forums and a community that can bolster your knowledge and community support for that specific item. For example, HP has a vast network of forums for both the IT Pro and the consumer (even if th eoverall experience on HP's web sites is approximately as pleasant as brushing your teeth with a bench grinder).

Notice that most of those area really just help forums and not so much a "hangout". That's because, in the end, I believe that you are right in noticing that there is a lack of a really awesome SysAdmin "hangout". I've been pining for one for years, but haven't quite found it. I think sysadmin-network.com is the closest thing so far, but it could use a little meat on its bones. That will come with time, I hope, as its relatively new.

I look forward to seeing what other people can contribute. Of course, if you find anything on your own, let us all know about it. =)

Answer (score 3):

check out http://planetsysadmin.com/ it's a nice aggregator for sysadmins blog

Answer (score 1):

The primary one that I can think of is Sysadmin Network - http://www.sysadmin-network.com

It's not big yet, but it's growing, and there's a few hundred members. It concentrates more on the social networking side.

Other than that, do you have a blog?

You might check this question too: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/73140/it-community-or-and-blog-sites/73173#73173

Answer (score 1):

For a community with a Microsoft Systems Management, Administration and Deployment bent check out [myITforum.com](http://myitforum.com/aboutus/) as they have some really good [articles](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/), great [forums](http://www.myitforum.com/forums/) on the following:

- [Patch Management](http://myitforum.com/articles/20/section.asp)
- [Active Directory and Group Policy](http://myitforum.com/articles/32/section.asp)
- [Windows PowerShell](http://myitforum.com/articles/40/section.asp)
- [System Center Operations Manager](http://myitforum.com/articles/43/section.asp) (SCOM)
- [System Center Configuration Manager](http://myitforum.com/articles/42/section.asp) (SCCM)
- [App-V](http://myitforum.com/articles/44/section.asp)
- [Deployment](http://myitforum.com/articles/47/section.asp) including User State Migration Tool (USMT) and Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT)
- ...and more.

Comment: Although I'd like to see everyone come here for everything (and I bet they eventually will), MyITForum is still the best place for the stuff listed above.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows stuff, I like the [Sysinternals forums](http://forum.sysinternals.com/).